# BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup, maintenance-plans, error-log

Not sure if this is a false-positive issue or not, but I need quell my curiosity about it.  I get the following error message:

> Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   
> BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE DBApp. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.

I get this error fairly often, but here is the kicker, when I check the backup folder for the DB in question, the .trn & .bak file are there.  So, it appears it is backing it up, but stating it failed.  The backup is performed by a maintenance plan and it finishes fine while backing up all the subsequent databases.

Any thoughts or should I just completely ignore this from now on as long as the DB is listed in the backup folder?

Comment: Maybe it was the post-completion checks that failed. Maybe it didn't complete successfully - did you actually try *restoring* the .bak/.trn files? Just because a file is there doesn't mean it's usable. Also did you check the logs like the error message suggested?

Comment: There must be some message logged can you look for that this support article would help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646329

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to mention that I did go through the SQL Error Logs.  What I posted is all that was there, no further details before or after the error message.  I find this strange as there is usually a detailed message

Comment: As far as the restore goes, will I receive an error if the database is corrupted in some way?  I'll get to that task shortly, just trying to understand where you're leading me.

Comment: Yes it can be due to corruption. Can you run restore verify only on database backup to check its consistency. You can also try restoring backup as restore is best way to check about corruption

Comment: Restore with verifyonly wont actually check the file completely.  I believe it just checks that the header is right and that it is, in fact, a sql backup file so I don't think that will be that much help.  The only true way to check them would be to actually restore it.  I restore all of mine 1x/week to our dev servers just to be safe.  A backup is not a backup if it doesn't actually work. :)

Comment: No matter what I've done, I get the error "Restore of database 'DBApp' failed.  However, the Tail-Log backup operation completed successfully."

Comment: Why are you doing a tail-log backup operation as part of a restore operation? Also you may find details in `msdb..sysjobhistory` about issues that occurred during the job that weren't severe enough to make it to the error log.

Comment: It isn't intentional to do the tail-log backup, SSMS is doing that on its own for some reason.  What I've done is created an empty container for the database I want to restore on my test server.  Then, I right-click the database in SSMS to perform a restore.  I select the full backup file as well as all the hourly log backups that day and hit OK.  Afterwards, it immediately fails with the aforementioned error.  Am I performing this procedure improperly somehow?

Comment: I found the error of my ways and removed the tail-log backup, but the restore process still fails immediately.  I'm pretty new to querying with TSQL code, so I'm not sure how to go about checking msdb.sysjobhistory.

Comment: New info about this matter: I get a lack of space error, which I know isn't true as I have MORE than enough space to restore.  The database is 7.34GB and I have over 95GB free on the drive.  The exact error message is: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: There is insufficient free space on disk volume 'D:\' to create the database. The database requires 229383340032 additional free bytes, while only 102419660800 bytes are available. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)"

Comment: I just thought of something after I posted my previous message.  That is the size of the backup file on disk after compression.  Upon looking at the live database properties on the originating server, the database in question is over 213GB, which is obviously higher than my 95GB free :-/

Comment: Got the database in question restored to my test server and the consistency check produced no errors.  I'll have to assume what Aaron stated was the cause...post-completion check failure.

Comment: How do we go about closing this question as answered for someone else's future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a post-completion check failure as there is no evidence elsewhere stating otherwise.

Comment: Funny, i get a negative mark on this answer, but agreed with Aaron Bertrand who has positive marks for the same answer.  Must be someone looking for an easy badge instead of a legit AND easy badge.  I love the internet!

Answer (score 0):

> Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.  BACKUP failed to complete the
> command BACKUP DATABASE DBApp. Check the backup application log for
> detailed messages.

- You will get the above error message whenever your database is in a offline state.

  Whenever you get the above error; kindly check the state of the database.
- You can also use the following T-SQL in order to check the database details.

> select * from sys.databases where name ='YourDatabaseName'